# Login With Evernote

Tags: node.js, meteor, oauth, evernote

I'm trying to connect Evernote with Meteor.

But I'm having a really bad time, trying to get the Oauth token, I was trying to follow this example [Evernote Sample Meteor](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/tree/master/sample/meteor), but is pretty old (2 years), but I tried to follow it and I got the idea.

I can get the connect to evernote, the login page and the email verification, my problem raised on the Meteor Method.

[handleCallback](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/blob/master/sample/meteor/server/server.coffee), which need the "verify" param, which in this case is the

```
ouath_token
```

Second try.

On the [evernote npm README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evernote) they suggest to use oAuthjs, and I try with this code.

```
var hostName = "http://sandbox.evernote.com";
    var options,oauth;
      options = {
        consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        callbackUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/auth',
        signatureMethod : "HMAC-SHA1",
      };
      oauth.request({'method': 'GET', 'url': hostName + '/oauth',
                   'success': function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                   }, 'failure': function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                   }});
```

But it returns

> (STDERR) No valid request transport found.

So I'm pretty stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

The npm module provided by Evernote includes helper functions to get OAuth working.

Install the Evernote npm module via:

```
  $npm install evernote
```

Below is the simplest single file example of implementing OAuth in a Evernote application I could put together.  Just change the values of `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` below and it should run just fine if you've installed Evernote:

```
var Evernote = require('evernote').Evernote;
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

CONSUMER_KEY="Put your consumer key here";
CONSUMER_SECRET="put your consumer secret here";

if (CONSUMER_KEY === "Put your consumer key here"){
  console.error("\nPlease enter your Evernote consumer key and secret\n\nIf you don't have a key you can get one at:\nhttps://dev.evernote.com/#apikey\n")
  process.exit(1)
}

var global = {};
global.oauthToken = '';
global.oauthSecret = '';

function getOauthVerifier(url) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]oauth_verifier=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var handler = function(request, response) {
  var params = url.parse(request.url)
  var pathname = params.pathname;
  console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

  var client = new Evernote.Client ({
    consumerKey: "Put your consumer key here",
    consumerSecret: "put your consumer secret here",
    sandbox: true
  });

  if (pathname == "/"){
    var callbackUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/oauth';

    client.getRequestToken(callbackUrl, function(err, oauthToken, oauthSecret, results){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        global.oauthToken = oauthToken;
        global.oauthSecret = oauthSecret;
        console.log("set oauth token and secret");
        var authorizeUrl = client.getAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken);
        console.log(authorizeUrl);
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        response.write("Please <a href=\""+authorizeUrl+"\">click here</a> to authorize the application");
        response.end();
      }
    });
  }
  else if (pathname == "/oauth"){
    client.getAccessToken(
      global.oauthToken, 
      global.oauthSecret, 
      getOauthVerifier(params.search), 
      function(error, oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, results) {
        if(error) {
          console.log("error\n\n\n");
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          response.write(oauthAccessToken);
          response.end();
        }   
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.write("not a valid URL <a href=\"/\"> GO HOME </a>");
    response.end();
  }
};


http.createServer(handler).listen(8888);
```